# My electronic snare sounds so hollow, I can hear it over the music. How can I fix this?

Tags: sound, electronic-drumset, snare-drum

I recently bought a Millenium MPS-850. Sounds reasonable, but especially the snare drum sounds so hollow, you could mistake it for an actual percussion instrument.

It's so loud, that I can hear it over the snare sound effect in my headphones. The thing has tightening screws, but except for maybe the drum feel of the netting, I don't think it will actually do anything.

Are there common solutions for this? Like opening it up and lining it with something?

I've called the vendor and they suggested tightening the mesh and said, that double ply would not help much, which makes sense, since it seems to be a problem with the snare body, not the net.

Something that came to my mind is, that the snare is closed off at the bottom, which normal snares are not. Should I drill holes into the bottom? Haha.

Comment: I guess your issue is just that it sounds _too loud_? I mean, _how_ an electric drum sounds, “hollow” or whatever, shouldn't really matter as it's not really supposed to be audible at all. But honestly, the fact that you hear it over your headphones-snare shouldn't really worry you; that it excessively disturbs the neighbours (defeating the main point of an electronic set) is of course a valid concern though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Maybe worry is not the right word, but I didn't expect to hear a clonk noise, whenever I want to hear a snare, tbh. Maybe I should've done more research, but I figured that's not how it worked.